# How to release a MacOS AND iOS app under the same app in App Store connect with Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, app-store-connect, release

Everything is in the title, to add a bit more specifications :

- I have my ios app with the bundle ID : com.myapp.ios
- I have my macos app with the bundle ID : com.myapp.macos

In app store connect, there is a button "Add a Macos app" :

[image]

So i wonder how to proceed in flutter as the MacOS project is a separate project from the iOS one.

I have also seen that in Xcode, on the iOS project, you can "Enable support for MacOS" and it adds the requirements.
However, still using Flutter, is this the correct way to do things ?

My goal is to simply release a MacOS app using the same app Name as my iOS one (logic it's the same app) and a different bundle ID to make the platform unique (for third party services and debug).

Note : I have asked Apple developer support about it but they still haven't answered in 3 days it's very long and i need an answer..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't hold your breathe waiting for Apple Dev support to help with a Flutter question.

Comment: If the apps have different bundle IDs then they will be different apps in App Store Connect. If you set the up with the same bundle ID then you can publish them under a single app in App Store Connect. Either way, it is simply a matter of adding a macOS target to your project and running a flutter build for Mac.  If you add support for macOS to your iOS target then you allow the app to run on M1 Macs as an iPad style app.  it is not a full, native macOS app. A native macOS app can run on both Intel and M1 macs

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment, so i should create a new App for MacOS as i have built specific changes and i don't want an "ipad style".